# Converting an excel file to a specific Json in python using openpyxl library

Tags: python, json, pandas

[image]
[image]

I have the Excel data with the format shown in the image preview. How can I convert it into a JSON using Python?

Expected Output:

file_name = [
{
A: Measurement(
time=10,
X1=1,
X2=4
),
B: Measurement(
time=10,
X1=1.2,
X2=4.1
),
C: Measurement(
time=10,
X1=1,
X2=4
)
},
{
A: Measurement(
time=11,
X1=1.1,
X2=4
),
B: Measurement(
time=11,
X1=1,
X2=4.2
),
C: Measurement(
time=11,
X1=1,
X2=4
)
},
{
A: Measurement(
time=12,
X1=1.3,
X2=4.1
),
B: Measurement(
time=12,
X1=1,
X2=4.1
),
C: Measurement(
time=12,
X1=1.2,
X2=3.9
)
}
]

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

The desired output can be achieved using nested dictionary objects.

```py
import openpyxl
import json
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'd:/temp/data.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.active
data_dict = {}
# skipping header
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    device_id, time, X1, X2 = row
    hour = time.hour  # Extract hour from the time
    if hour not in data_dict:
        data_dict[hour] = {}
    data_dict[hour][device_id] = (hour, X1, X2)
# dictionary to JSON
json_data = []
for hour, measurements in data_dict.items():
    json_data.append({device_id: 
      f"Measurement( time={hour}, X1={X1}, X2={X2} )" 
      for device_id, (hour, X1, X2) in measurements.items()})
file_name = json.dumps(json_data, indent=2)    
print(file_name)
```

**Output**

```
[                                                                                             
  {                                                                                           
    "A": "Measurement( time=10, X1=1, X2=4 )",                                                
    "B": "Measurement( time=10, X1=1.2, X2=4.1 )",                                            
    "C": "Measurement( time=10, X1=1, X2=4 )"                                                 
  },                                                                                          
  {                                                                                           
    "A": "Measurement( time=11, X1=1, X2=4 )",                                                
    "B": "Measurement( time=11, X1=1.2, X2=4.1 )",                                            
    "C": "Measurement( time=11, X1=1, X2=4 )"                                                 
  }                                                                                           
]
```

---

**Update**

Revised the code for new requirement in comment.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
data = pd.read_excel(r'd:\temp\data.xlsx')
data['time_str'] = data['time'].apply(lambda t: t.strftime("%Y, %#m, %#d, %H, %M"))
grouped = data.groupby('time_str').apply(lambda g: g.to_dict(orient='records')).tolist()
output = []
for measurements in grouped:
    mea_dict = {}
    for meamnt in measurements:
        device_id = meamnt['Device_id']
        x1 = meamnt['X1']
        x2 = meamnt['X2']
        time_str = meamnt['time_str']
        mea_str = f"Measurement( calculated_date=datetime({time_str}), X1={x1}, X2={x2} )"
        mea_dict[device_id] = mea_str
    output.append(mea_dict)
fname = json.dumps(output, indent=2)
print(fname)
```

**Output**

```
[                                                                                             
  {                                                                                           
    "A": "Measurement( calculated_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 00), X1=1.0, X2=4.0 )",       
    "B": "Measurement( calculated_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 00), X1=1.2, X2=4.1 )",       
    "C": "Measurement( calculated_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 00), X1=1.0, X2=4.0 )"        
  },                                                                                          
  {                                                                                           
    "A": "Measurement( calculated_date=datetime(2023, 2, 1, 10, 10), X1=1.0, X2=4.0 )",       
    "B": "Measurement( calculated_date=datetime(2023, 2, 1, 10, 10), X1=1.2, X2=4.1 )",       
    "C": "Measurement( calculated_date=datetime(2023, 2, 1, 10, 10), X1=1.0, X2=4.0 )"        
  }                                                                                           
]
```

Comment: What is min_row=2 used for? Besides, in my actual file, I have datetime which includes the date as well as the time. It should appear like calculated_date=datetime(2020, 7, 20, 18, 26). How does it change the code?

Comment: `min_row=2` is for skipping header (the comment in code mentioined it). Please include the data which is exactly as your actual file in OP. It should be a Minimal, Reproducible Example data.

Comment: I added a second table. Thank you @taller_ExcelHome

Comment: What's the expected result? `time=10`only catched hour.

Comment: calculated_date=datetime(2020, 7, 20, 18, 26)

Comment: calculated_date=datetime(2020, 7, 20, 18, 26). Please see this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76901686/converting-an-excel-file-to-a-specific-json-in-python-using-openpyxl-library-wit)