# Converting an excel file to a specific Json in python using openpyxl library with datetime

Tags: python, json, pandas, excel, openpyxl

[image]

I have the Excel data with the format shown in the image preview. How can I convert it into a JSON using Python?

Expected Output:

file_name = [
{
A: Measurement(
calculated_date=datetime(2022, 10, 1, 4, 18),
X1=1,
X2=4
),
B: Measurement(
calculated_date=datetime(2022, 10, 1, 4, 18),
X1=1.2,
X2=4.1
),
C: Measurement(
calculated_date=datetime(2022, 10, 1, 4, 18),
X1=1,
X2=4
)
},
{
A: Measurement(
calculated_date=datetime(2022, 10, 2, 3, 18),
X1=1.1,
X2=4
),
B: Measurement(
calculated_date=datetime(2022, 10, 2, 3, 18),
X1=1,
X2=4.2
),
C: Measurement(
calculated_date=datetime(2022, 10, 2, 3, 18),
X1=1,
X2=4
)
},
{
A: Measurement(
calculated_date=datetime(2022, 10, 3, 9, 48),
X1=1.3,
X2=4.1
),
B: Measurement(
calculated_date=datetime(2022, 10, 3, 9, 48),
X1=1,
X2=4.1
),
C: Measurement(
calculated_date=datetime(2022, 10, 3, 9, 48),
X1=1.2,
X2=3.9
)
}
]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an excel file to a specific Json in python using openpyxl library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76901194/converting-an-excel-file-to-a-specific-json-in-python-using-openpyxl-library)

Comment: @taller_Excelhome I don't know what to do with the datetime column?

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome your link is to this post...

Answer (score 0):

This should get the desired output:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from datetime import datetime
import json

def load_excel_data(file_path):
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
    sheet = workbook.active
    return sheet

def convert_excel_datetime(excel_datetime_str):
    return datetime.strptime(str(excel_datetime_str), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def create_measurement_dict(time, x1, x2):
    return {
        'calculated_date': time,
        'X1': x1,
        'X2': x2
    }

def main():
    excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
    sheet = load_excel_data(excel_file)

    json_data = []
    current_date = None
    entry = {}

    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
        device_id, row_time, x1, x2 = row
        parsed_time = convert_excel_datetime(row_time)

        if parsed_time.date() != current_date:
            if current_date:
                json_data.append(entry)
            current_date = parsed_time.date()
            entry = {}

        measurement = create_measurement_dict(parsed_time, x1, x2)
        entry[device_id] = 'Measurement(' + str(measurement) + ')'

    json_data.append(entry)

    print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "A": "Measurement({'calculated_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 4, 18), 'X1': 1, 'X2': 4})",    
        "B": "Measurement({'calculated_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 4, 18), 'X1': 1.2, 'X2': 4.1})",
        "C": "Measurement({'calculated_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 4, 18), 'X1': 1, 'X2': 4})"     
    },
    {
        "A": "Measurement({'calculated_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 2, 3, 18), 'X1': 1.1, 'X2': 4})",
        "B": "Measurement({'calculated_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 2, 3, 18), 'X1': 1, 'X2': 4.2})",
        "C": "Measurement({'calculated_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 2, 3, 18), 'X1': 1, 'X2': 4})"
    },
    {
        "A": "Measurement({'calculated_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 3, 9, 48), 'X1': 1.3, 'X2': 4.1})",
        "B": "Measurement({'calculated_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 3, 9, 48), 'X1': 1, 'X2': 4.1})",
        "C": "Measurement({'calculated_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 3, 9, 48), 'X1': 1.2, 'X2': 3.9})"
    }
]
```